What is wrong with this CSS when try to validate?
When I validate my CSS, the following triggers an parse error:
.srow {
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        gap: 1em;
        * {
            flex: 1;
        }
    }
    .aside {
        flex: 0 25%;
        @media (max-width: 500px) {
            flex: 0 100%;
        }
    }

If I remove both the .gap and @media blocks, no error. What is wrong with the CSS?

That is not CSS, but SCSS (or a similar derivative language). CSS does not support nesting. gap is fine, it is the * { ... } inside the .srow rule that is the issue; similarly, as you say, @media (...) { ... } inside the .aside rule.

Your CSS is fine. The validator however, has not been updated to recognise nesting yet,

@Amadan - See https://drafts.csswg.org/css-nesting-1/ and https://caniuse.com/css-nesting

Not an elegant solution from a more coding guy than CSS guy, but this works:
.srow {
display: flex;
flex-wrap: wrap;
gap: 1em;
}
.srow * {
flex: 1;
}
.aside {
flex: 0 25%;
}
@media (width < 500px) {
.aside {
flex: 0 100%;
}
}

@Alohci Thank you, I was not aware of that yet. However, that is an Editor's Draft module (one of the least reliable types among W3C documents). While you can apparently use it on many browsers, it is not yet officially part of the CSS, and it would be correct for a validator to reject it. It is also probably best to not use it yet.

@Amadan it's officially part of the CSS. The drafting part means that few things may still change but the main functionality is there and works fine (it's even baseline since 2023 so it's safe to use). It also have a "working draft" version: https://www.w3.org/TR/css-nesting-1/ since 2023

@TemaniAfif How is it "officially" part of CSS? CSS standard is set by W3C, and both working draft and editor's draft are explicitly defined as not endorsed by W3C (in the link I shared above); it explicitly says "These drafts MUST NOT be cited as W3C standards". Whether it is supported by most browsers or not, whether it is endorsed by Baseline or not, is irrelevant to what the standard is.

@Amadan anything in the Specification is written by the W3C (no one else write the Spec) and before any Spec is written, the feature is approved to be "part of the CSS". Many features stay too long at "working draft" or "editor draft" because it requires a lot of time to fine tune things and to do this, browsers need to implement the feature and people need to use the feature. You cannot finalize the Spec if there is no real usage. Also it doesn't make a lot of sense to spend time writing the Spec for something not yet part of the CSS.

.srow {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    gap: 1em;
}

.srow > * {
    flex: 1;
}

.aside {
    flex: 0 25%;
}

@media (max-width: 500px) {
    .aside {
        flex: 0 100%;
    }
}


.srow > * { ... } is not equivalent to .srow { * { ... } }, .srow * { ... } is.

Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?
